# How to read reviews from google chrome webstore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension in the webstore. I would like to read the reviews against my extension from my extension . I tried injecting a .js page into my extension's review page but I get the error "Tab was closed".
Here is my code:

```
var popup=window.open("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/convergehub-lead-generato/mjcffemmfdpcjekgonelgmphacdhhbod/reviews");
chrome.tabs.getSelected( null, function( tab ) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( tab.id, { file: "./lib/reviews.js", runAt: "document_end" }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });
});
```

In my reviews.js there is only 1 line 
alert("here");

In the above code I always get the alert "Tab was closed". Is there any other way to get the reviews ? Am I doing something wrong here ? Is this even allowed on the webstore page ?

Comment: Chrome forbids content scripts in its webstore. You'll have to reverse-engineer their page code and network requests using devtools, and get the info manually. Might fail though if their internal API is token-protected.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you share a link where this might be documented ?

Comment: Nowhere, I would think, because it's an internal thing. As for reverse-engineering, it's just a technical term.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was looking for a link where "Chrome forbids content scripts in its webstore" might be explained or documented.

Comment: [Chrome Extension Content Script on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](//stackoverflow.com/q/11613371)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks I will check it out